# How to access the calendar of a Microsoft Exchange on-premise installation

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

With [EWS being deprecated](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/upcoming-changes-to-exchange-web-services-ews-api-for-office-365/), what is a currently working and future-proof way to create applications that interact with the Exchange calendar without using a hybrid deployment?

MS is obviously heavily pushing the Graph API, but it only seems to work when Exchange is [connected to the cloud](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/office-365-rest-apis-for-mail-calendars-and-contacts) in one way or another (hybrid deployment, O365, Exchange online). Older answers to similar questions point to the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/calendar-rest-operations), which also is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Good question.  In order to support Graph on-prem Windows AD would need to support OAuth.  I thought I had read something about that being supported in E2019 (at least for EWS), but frankly, I've not really looked into it.  EWS will likely have to be fully supported, albeit stabilized, indefinitely until Graph can run on-prem.  Suggest you search thru MS Graph blogosphere for more concrete info, because that seems to be where everything in the Office world is converging.